# I get cannot open database error when trying to open the database?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following this tutorial. I did everything according to the tutroial. However, I am getting an error when I am trying to open the database. It says "cannot open the database requested by the login". I am using visual studio 2012 express. The tutorial is using 2013. Could that be a problem? Here is my connection string.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SchoolContext" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity;Integrated Security=True;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

The tutorial I am following. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2012 installed, you most likely don't have SQL Server **2012 Express** which is needed for using the `(localdb)\v11.0` feature.

If you have an earlier version of SQL Server **Express** installed, then you should try to use this connection string instead:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="SchoolContext" 
        connectionString="server=.\SQEXPRESS;database=ContosoUniversity;Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

and then basically EF should create your database on your local SQL Server Express instance and use it from there.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the ASPNET/Network NT account into the list of users allowed to access the DB. ASP.NET apps use the NT Service account/ASPNET account by default on the app pool.

take a look here and scroll to the SQL Server section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx